# In Jenkins freestyle job, how can I set a variable and use it in a "Conditional step (single)" step?

Tags: jenkins

I have a free-style Jenkins job with an "Execute shell" step. In it, I have an `if()` condition and when the condition is satisfied, I set a variable `TRIGGER_JOB=true`, a variable that I initially set to `false` in the `Inject environment variables to the build process -> Script Content` box of the job, and I do see that the variable gets set to `true`.

Now I want to add a "Conditional step (single)" to this job, and set it so it's "Run" drop-down box is set to "Boolean condition," and a "TOKEN" set to `$TRIGGER_JOB`, the above variable. However, I get this error

```
Exception caught evaluating condition: [org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.MacroEvaluationException: Unrecognized macro 'TRIGGER_JOB' in '$TRIGGER_JOB'], action = [Don't run]
```

How do I fix this? What are alternatives?

Comment: Tested your scenario and it works fine to me, maybe related to something like [JENKINS-13347](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-13347), try to use `${ENV,var="TRIGGER_JOB"}` instead if `$TRIGGER_JOB`

Comment: @NoamHelmer, thanks. You mean to use that syntax in the "Conditional step(single)" correct?

Comment: yes instead of the `$TRIGGER_JOB`

Comment: I get `[Boolean condition] checking [null] against [^(1|y|yes|t|true|on|run)$] (origin token: ${ENV,var="TRIGGER"})`